# Instrument tagging standards

Tags: discussion, tags

I wanted to ask a question about bass guitar, and I realized that since this is now a universal music site, that I can't just use "bass" as a tag like I could on the Guitars.SE due to potential confusion with the double-bass.

If I want to tag a question for bass guitar, should I use "bass guitar" or "bass" and "guitar"? For the former case, I can see it being more useful for keeping the tag list succinct and being easier to favorite/ignore. For the latter case, some questions about bass sound/technique may be applicable to both bass guitar and double-bass.

If one was playing an acoustic bass guitar, should one then use "acoustic bass guitar," "acoustic" and "bass guitar" as two tags, or "acoustic," "bass," and "guitar" as three separate tags?

As you can see, this can get all kinds of confusing, and I'm wondering if there is a standard that the community has agreed upon, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 12):

I recommend [bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-guitar) for the first, so that it's distinguished from standup bass.  Tagging [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) and [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) would mean that your question is both about bass and guitar, which is not your intention.

The rest follows from that; you should use [acoustic-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass-guitar) because it follows the same format, even though [acoustic-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass) should be unambiguous since there's no reason to add "acoustic" for a standup bass.  Likewise, [electric-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-bass-guitar) for questions limited solely to electric bass.

I think [double-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-bass) should be used as well, just to make it clear that it's not bass guitar.  I doubt there will be general bass questions (both double bass and bass guitar), so we shouldn't have [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) at all.

---

**Summary:** Use [bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-guitar) and [double-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-bass).  If questions are truly limited to them, use [electric-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-bass-guitar) and [acoustic-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass-guitar).

Comment: Apply the same rules to non-bass guitars, as well.  `guitar` for the generic, with `electric-guitar`, `acoustic-guitar`, `classical-guitar`, etc. for the limited cases.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the clarification. I was worried about tags getting too specific, as I'm also used to the somewhat modular tagging system we use in Gaming. :)

Comment: Specific tags are good for instruments - the difference between a [baroque-flute] and [flute] are pretty significant :)

Comment: Yep.  I think the generally encouraged idea is to use `baroque-flute` if the question is specifically about that type of flute, and not just if you happen to be using a baroque flute and are asking a general question.

Comment: @Matthew I'm unaccepting my answer, which has nothing to do with the quality of yours, but mostly for the fact it looks like this is becoming a discussion about tagging standards for several types of instruments and there won't really be any one, single answer to accept.

Comment: @FallenAngelsEyes That's a good idea, no worries.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid just using [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) to refer to an instrument since that tag could/should be applied to, for example, composition questions on aspects of constructing a bass line in music independent of the instrumentation.

Comment: And bass recorders, and the bass vocal part, and...

Comment: ...And the bass drum, bass trombone, bass clarinet, bass sax, bass trumpet, double bass, bass flute, tuba (AKA the BASS)...

Comment: These comments are contrary to my intended point: the generic tag [tag:bass] shouldn't be used to indicate any instrument, but rather to something more like the role of bass as a voice/tambre independent  of instrument.

Answer (score 3):

Tags should be able to stand alone. If a tag only make sense in the context of another tag, it is not appropriate. So using "bass" as a short name for the double bass in the viol family is okay, but using "bass" as a modifier for another instrument ("bass" "clarinet", "bass" "saxophone", "bass" "guitar") is not good.

In your case you may want to tag "bass-guitar" (replace all spaces by dashes, since spaces are not allowed in tag names). If you have an acoustic bass guitar question, I would suggest tagging it both "bass-guitar" and "acoustic-guitar". An "acoustic-bass-guitar" tag is probably too specific, not to mention too long for a tag name.

Comment: The character limit is 26 for tags, I believe.  `acoustic-bass-guitar` isn't too specific if the question is strictly not about electric bass.

Comment: It's 26? I thought it was 20.. my bad. (Also, that still means I counted wrong.)

Comment: The max tag length is 25.

Comment: My bad, I blame Gaming.SE for the confusion :P

Comment: @Rebecca, it should be 32. ;)

Comment: I would suggest using acoustic-guitar as a tag for a question regarding bass guitars (whether acoustic or not) would not be a good idea, as that goes against all common usage, and the two instruments are so different.

Answer (score 2):

I propose that we use [violin-family](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/violin-family) when a question applies to any member instead of manually adding [violin](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/violin) [viola](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viola) [cello](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cello) [double-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-bass).

Comment: This is probably a good idea.  Is there a more common name than `violin-family`? Maybe `bowed-instruments`?

Comment: Well, this would include tromba marina, musical saw, viols, viola da gamba and various other instruments. I think [tag:bowed-instruments] might be useful in its own right alongside [tag:violin-family].

Comment: OK.  I've unfortunately never played one besides fiddling with my dad's cello, so I wouldn't know whether the distinction is useful :)

Comment: We will have more basis for reflexion during the public beta.

Comment: `string-instruments`?

Comment: @Ben: This would include guitar, harp, psalterion, ukulele, koto, etc.

Comment: @ogerard Oh, that's true. Never mind.