# Guitar question tagging conventions

Tags: discussion, tags

Hi Guys,

I was pretty active on the guitars.se site, and in my effort to make the merge a success, I'm about to embark on tagging/retagging any unorganised questions from the old site that made the merge. However, before I start, I just wanted to check that the way I am going to tag the questions is the way that everyone else would agree with. My way is pretty much explained by Matthew Read's first answer to [this question,](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/instrument-tagging-standards) applied to bass guitars:

> I recommend [bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-guitar) for the first, so that it's distinguished from standup bass.  Tagging [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) and [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) would mean that your question is both about bass and guitar, which is not your intention.
>
> The rest follows from that; you should use [acoustic-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass-guitar) because it follows the same format, even though [acoustic-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass) should be unambiguous since there's no reason to add "acoustic" for a standup bass.  Likewise, [electric-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-bass-guitar) for questions limited solely to electric bass.
>
> I think [double-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-bass) should be used as well, just to make it clear that it's not bass guitar.  I doubt there will be general bass questions (both double bass and bass guitar), so we shouldn't have [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) at all.
>
> **Summary:** Use [bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-guitar) and [double-bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-bass).  If questions are truly limited to them, use [electric-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-bass-guitar) and [acoustic-bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-bass-guitar).

Obviously I would be using this standard applied to guitars (electric, acoustic, 12 string etc).

Just wanted to check everyone else agrees with me, I don't want to start off wrong, so that everyone has to go and clear up my mess (not that I wouldn't myself obviously :) )

Comment: Well, I'm obviously down with that ... :P It's also how I've tagged a ton of the imported questions, so I do hope I don't have to redo it all!

Comment: Fab. Will crack on in the morning :D

Comment: BTW, relevant discussion on meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93126/handling-of-inherited-tags

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that's the standard that makes the most sense and is agreed upon by our community. We mods can also mass-retag things so the most important decision here is the use of a single tag instead of more than one and I don't think anyone is disputing the advantages of that.